# new to java - understanding java compilation

Tags: java, android

Java programs can be compiled into an `.exe` then someone can click on this `.exe` icon and run the app. 
My questions are:

- Is that the only way a java program can be compiled and ran?
- Is it possible to just write a class.java file, put this file on the
  server, and expect it to "start working"  without any kind of exe?
- Are there other ways to compile java programs other than creating an
  `.exe` or `.apk` file (Android)?

Comment: After compiling you see an exe file? I highly doubt it

Comment: for android http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java class is compiled to form a `.jar` file and not an `.exe` file

A `Jar file` is essentially a collection of files (mostly archives of java classes) in one file, similar to a ZIP file. A Jar file facilitates the packaging of applications into one file. In addition to the Java class files and resources, a Jar file can contain a META-INF directory. The most important file in this directory is manifest.mf. It is used to define extension and package related data. The Main-Class: classname in the manifest file specifies the class that gets executed first.

Comment: so do you double click on the .jar file and it launches the application ? does one java program produce more than one .jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

A way I run text-based java programs is I make it into a .jar and then excecute it in CMD using `java -jar nameOfJar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are usually distributed as runnable jar packages, not exe where all java files are compiled into class files.
 You must consider that exe files are executable on `Windows` platform, but not in `*nix`, `Solaris`, etc.
So you can create `.jar` file. It runs on every platform which have installed `JRE`.

For android, you can create .apk file and that is it. Not an exe file!

Answer (score 0):

Java programs are compiled to .class files that run on a Java Virtual Machine. The way to execute a Java Virtual Machine depends on the Operative System you are using.

Also .class files can be packaged on .jar, .war or .ear files.

Answer (score 0):

At first, JAVA programs are not compiled to .EXE, they are compiled to .CLASS files which can be packaged into a .JAR files. You can simply distribute the .JAR files which can be directly executed when the system has JAVA Runtime installed.

Also please note that .EXE files are Windows Executables and cannot be run under other operating system environments but there are tools that convert .JAR files to .EXE files such as JSmooth and Launch4J.